# Why we use NLS_INSTANCE_PARAMETER?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

For eg :

```
Select * from nls_instance_parameter
where parameter = 'NLS_DATE_FORMAT';

PARAMETER               VALUE
NLS_DATE_FORMAT         DD-MON-RR
```

Can anyone explain when to use NLS_INSTANCE_PARAMETER ? and What is NLS_INSTANCE_PARAMETER ?

Answer (score 2):

If set, the NLS_INSTANCE_PARAMETERS override the settings from NLS_DATABASE_PARAMETERS, but are in turn overridden by NLS_SESSION_PARAMETERS.

There is some information about this [in the docuemntation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10729/ch3globenv.htm#NLSPG194):

> When a new database is created during the execution of the CREATE DATABASE statement, the NLS-related database configuration is established. The current NLS instance parameters are stored in the data dictionary along with the database and national character sets. The NLS instance parameters are read from the initialization parameter file at instance startup.

[And](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10729/ch3globenv.htm#NLSPG195);

> Applications can check the session, instance, and database NLS parameters by querying the following data dictionary views:
>
> - NLS_SESSION_PARAMETERS shows the NLS parameters and their values for the session that is querying the view. It does not show information about the character set.
> - NLS_INSTANCE_PARAMETERS shows the current NLS instance parameters that have been explicitly set and the values of the NLS instance parameters.
> - NLS_DATABASE_PARAMETERS shows the values of the NLS parameters for the database. The values are stored in the database.

There is an order of precedence for NLS settings. If a session does not explicitly set an NLS parameter then the instance setting is used; if the instance has not explicitly set that parameter then the database setting is used.

[NLS_DATE_FORMAT](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40402/initparams147.htm#REFRN10119) is a good example of something that's likely to change. The database has a default format set when it is created. If the pfile/spfile specifies it then that takes precedence when the instance is started. New sessions will use the instance setting, or if it wasn't explicitly set, will inherit the database setting. But many clients will set NLS_DATE_FORMAT - for example, SQL Developer lets you set that and other NLS settings through its preferences; and you can do `ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT ...` to change it again for the duration of your session.

You're unlikely to need to refer to NLS_INSTANCE_PARAMETERS directly, as it won't necessarily tell you anything useful about the current session - since not all values are set and some may be overridden. It's more normal, I think, to query NLS_SESSION_PARAMETERS if you need to know about any of the current session settings.

Answer (score 1):

The table name is actually `nls_instance_parameters` (plural). It's all in [the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/server.920/a96529/ch3.htm).

> NLS parameters determine the locale-specific behavior on both the
>   client and the server.

So the one you've mentioned - [`NLS_DATE_FORMAT`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/server.920/a96529/ch3.htm#50035) - defines the default date format to use with the `TO_CHAR` and `TO_DATE` functions.

Nice example from the documentation:

> To set the default date format to display Roman numerals for the
>   month, include the following line in the initialization parameter
>   file:
>
> `NLS_DATE_FORMAT = "DD RM YYYY"`
>
> Enter the following SELECT statement:
>
> `SELECT TO_CHAR(SYSDATE) currdate FROM dual;`
>
> You should see the following output if today's date is February 12,
>   1997:
>   `12 II 1997`